# Exclude directive is not working on monorepo project

Tags: typescript

I have a monorepo project with the following arquitecture:

```sh
my-monorepo
├── packages
│   ├── package1
│   │     └── ./tsconfig.json(extend the root configuration)
│   ├── package2
│   │     └── ./tsconfig.json(extend the root configuration)
├── tsconfig.json(Root base ts configuration)
```

The problem with this is that I have in my root base configuration the option `exclude` but is not working. I have tried to set in each local `tsconfig.json` file for each package the `exlude` option but this did not work either.

### Root base ts configuration

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017", "ES2019"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "**/*.config.ts", "**/*.setup.ts"]
}
```

### Package 1/2 ts configuration

```json
{
  "extends": "../../../../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "**/*.config.ts", "**/*.setup.ts"]
}
```

What I want is to exclude the `jest.config.ts` file in root folder and in every package but this file still has ts errors, this file should be excluded according the glob `"**/*.config.ts"`, then I think that the transpiler is not taking this configuration.

Comment: Any solution? I think I'm running into the same thing wrt to `node_modules` in root in a monorepo using lerna/yarn workspaces.